# Play sound through multiple output devices (several usb headphones)?

Tags: c++, audio

I used to think you could only play from one device at a time in Windows. Recently I installed Virtual Audio Cable and learned that you could play sound from several devices at once with no problem. Is there anyway to get the same result using c++?

Comment: It's a kernel driver.  Are you asking how to write device drivers?

Comment: Nothing prevents you from playing audio through multiple devices simultaneously. All audio APIs including obsolete are capable of doing it.